# My program crashes if the vector is too large?

Tags: c, debugging, crash

When I test my program with large vectors, as in larger than 12 elements, it crashes (I get an lldb error). However, it works fine for small vectors. I think it's trying to access a memory space it shouldn't, but I have no idea how to fix it. 
The program is supposed to print out the vectors whose sum of elements are equal to the "target"
Also, is there a different way that I can express:  if (i & (1 << j)) ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int c = 0;
/* find subsets of a given set */
void findSubsets(int *value, int n, int i) {
    int j;
    if (i < 0)
        return;

    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        /*
         * checking jth bit is set in i.  If
         * it is set, then fetch the element at
         * jth index in value array
         */
            if (i & (1 << j)) {
                suma = suma + value[j];
        }

    /* recursive call */
    findSubsets(value, n, i - 1);
    return;
}

int main() {

    /* 2^n - indicates the possible no of subsets */
    int count = pow(2, size);

    /* finds the subsets of the given set */
    findSubsets(vector, size, count - 1);

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to be able to use this program for large vectors (up to about 20)

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you got `52428810` recursive function calls. This will cause a stack overflow. Instead of recursion, try iteration:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    findSubsets(vector, size, i);
}
```

And remove the recursive call within `findSubsets`.